# Can I have a custom Setup method in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to have a custom setup method like for a test where i talk to a webservice and get initial values. Can i do this in gatling?I only want to run this once per simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [before](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/general/simulation_structure.html?highlight=before#hooks) hook to perform any custom code before running the simulation. Note that you can't use Gatling's DSL in there. But you can use whatever Java HTTP client you want, from `java.net.UrlConnection` to `AsyncHttpClient` that Gatling ships.