# Sequential scenarios each with a different protocol

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a simulation where I first need an admin user to do certain things before a normal user can perform certain tasks.

```
val adminConf = http
.baseURL(server)
.headers(sentHeaders)
.basicAuth(admin, password)

val normalUserConf = http
.baseURL(server)
.headers(sentHeaders)
.basicAuth(normalUser, password)
```

At the moment I'm only able to run one scenario:

```
setUp(adminScenario
        .inject(atOnceUsers(1))
        .protocols(adminConf))
```

How can I run one scenario with the `adminConf` protocol and one scenario with the `normalUserConf` protocol **sequentially**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatling does not have API to run scenarios sequentially.

What you have described looks like setup step. I would recommend to use [before](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_structure/#hooks) hook to perform initial setup. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439925/can-i-have-a-custom-setup-method-in-gatling) relevant question.

Because inside `before` we don't have access to gatling we chose to use [sttp](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp) library that has API somewhat similar to gatling

```
sttp
  .cookie("login", "me")
  .body("This is a test")
  .post(uri"http://endpoint.com/secret")
  .send()
```